# Android get TypedArray dynamically

Tags: java, android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="level_2">
        <item name="first">some value</item>
        <item name="second">some value</item>
        <item name="third">some value</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

-

```
int currentLevel = 2;        
TypedArray testArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.level_2);
int firstValue = testArray.getInt(0,0);
```

I'm trying to dynamically set the resource (array) to use based on some data. For example, I have arrays for each level like the one above. Instead of using the resource id `R.array.level_2` in `obtainTypedArray()` I'd like to use the value of the int `currentLevel` in the example above.

So, some way of doing something like:
`obtainTypedArray("R.array.level_"+level)`

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Context.getResources().getIdentifier();` Method, at the below, can be called in any activity via `getStrArrWithId("level_" + level, getApplicationContext());`

```
public String [] getStrArrWithId (String id, Context context) {
    int arrId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(id, "array", context.getPackageName());
    String[] strArr = context.getResources().getStringArray(arrId);
    return strArr;
}
```